# Ruby on Rails and JSON parser from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

I use 'gem json' and need load JSON data from some **url**, for example:

`"http://locallhost:3000/qwerty/give_json.json"` with

```
{"one":"Omg","two":125,"three":"Hu"}
```

I have rails app

```
class QwertyController < ApplicationController
    require 'json'

    def get_json
        source = "http://localhost:3000/qwerty/give_json.json"
        @data = JSON.parse(JSON.load(source))
    end
end
```

I get error

```
JSON::ParserError in QwertyController#get_json
795: unexpected token at 'http://localhost:3000/qwerty/give_json.json'
```

In string:  @data = JSON.parse(JSON.load(source))

What is the matter? How can I get JSON data and parse it? I try @data["one"] ...

Comment: Looks like you have invalid JSON in the source

Comment: No it's not. I created a rails app, which generate JSON answer on port 3000 (http://localhost:3000/qwerty/give_json.json). And second app, which try to get JSON data on port 3001 (http://localhost:3001/qwerty/get_json)

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? you don't need to require json in newer versions of rails and ruby...

Comment: alexkd@Active-pc:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]
alexkd@Active-pc:~$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0

Comment: Yes you do have invalid JSON.  YOu are calling JSON.load on a URL string, not a JSON object.  That is invalid JSON.  JSON.load doesnt read data from a url, you are just passing the string in

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`JSON.load` takes a source that is a `String` or `IO` object according to the documentation

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load

```
[17] pry(main)> {hello: "World"}.to_json
=> "{\"hello\":\"World\"}"
[18] pry(main)> JSON.load(_)
=> {"hello"=>"World"}
```

You're giving it a String that is a URL and that's why you're getting an error. You can use `open-uri` to fetch the data from the URL to then be parsed by JSON like so...

```
[22] pry(main)> require 'open-uri'
=> false
[23] pry(main)> JSON.load(URI.open("https://api.github.com"))
=> {"current_user_url"=>"https://api.github.com/user",
 "authorizations_url"=>"https://api.github.com/authorizations",
 "emails_url"=>"https://api.github.com/user/emails",
 "emojis_url"=>"https://api.github.com/emojis",
 "events_url"=>"https://api.github.com/events",
 "feeds_url"=>"https://api.github.com/feeds",
 "following_url"=>"https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}",
 "gists_url"=>"https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}",
 "hub_url"=>"https://api.github.com/hub"}
```

**NOTE**

`URI.open` returns a `StringIO` object which responds to `read` returning the JSON data. JSON.load turns the data into a hash to be used.

To parse the JSON string you can either use `JSON.load` or `JSON.parse`

Comment: that is a really good solution!! I had to explicitly call `URI.open`, otherwise it gave me a `No such file or directory` error, but other then that, I found this to be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @wnm same for me. If it's like that for everyone we should probably edit the answer to include it. I have no idea if it's the way for everyone

Comment: It's likely that the `open` call may have worked in the past but now it's invoking Kernel#call which would return the error you're seeing now. I've updated the solution to include URI as part of the call

Answer (score 18):

You could use net/http library like below:

```
   require 'net/http'
   source = 'http://localhost:3000/qwerty/give_json.json'
   resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(source))
   data = resp.body
   result = JSON.parse(data)
```

Or the gem http party:

```
require 'httparty'

response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/qwerty/give_json.json')
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, `httparty` already includes the JSON library within **[httparty.rb](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L7)**.
This means that the call to `require 'json'` is unnecessary.

Thanks for providing these examples!

Answer (score 2):

You could use JSON and net/http lib.. which is  below:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = "https://api.url/"
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
data = JSON.parse(response)
objs.each do |data|
  title = data["title"]
```