# Parsing JSON from GET request in JavaScript/Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, web

I am currently trying to navigate to send a GET request to a URL, parse what is returned into a JSON and use it in my Javascript.

At the moment, I am using dummy data like so :

```
data = [
{
:id=> "1",
:rev=> "1.0",
:text=> "This is a test"
}]
```

And this works perfectly in my code :

```
<ul>
  <% data.each do |item| %>
  <li>
    ...
```

Now I have a webpage which returns the data after a GET request in this form :

```
{"alerts":[{"_id":"1","_rev":"1.0","text":"This is a test"}]}
```

when I call this, however, I am getting a connection refused error, here is my code :

```
# require 'open-uri'
# content = open("http://mywebsite.returnsDataAbove.com").read
```

and

```
# require 'net/http'
# require 'json'

# url = URI.parse('http://mywebsite.returnsDataAbove.com')
# req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
# res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  # http.request(req)
# }
# puts res.body
# hash = JSON.parse res.body
# puts hash
```

what have I done incorrectly here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: error information would be helpful, is not clear in your question what leads to what

Comment: mostly the last part, you write you have a webpage that returns the data, then you don't

Comment: @juanpastas if I navigate to the page using firefox data is returned, calling it from another webpage does not work

Comment: hmmm can't understand your redaction

Comment: @juanpastas If I go to http://mywebsite.returnsDataAbove.com via a normal browser call (i.e in Firefox) it will work and print the information on the screen. Calling my code above, however, results in a "connection refused" error being displayed on my screen. I am not sure how to debug this or provide anymore information - any help in this would be appreciated. Thank you very much :)

Comment: The error is triggered on line res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
   http.request(req)
 }. It will show no error message until this is called.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3647238/1197775, maybe is helpful

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/a/18581861/1197775